# How to decrease the weight of UILabel text font?

Tags: ios, size, uilabel, uifont

I'm trying to reduce the weight of font in UILabel text.
I'm using Helvetica font, still i want the text more thinner.
how can i reduce the thickness of UILabel text font weight?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the font to a different variant in the same family, for instance Helvetica-Light (where by default you get Helvetica-Regular). [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com) provide a nice site for viewing font options.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set an arbitrary weight for any font. Some fonts have a bold and regular variant. A smaller number also have a "light" variant. As the other poster said, if the font is one of those that has a light variant, you can select that, but you can't arbitrarily reduce the weight of a font.

Answer (score -3):

You need to reduce the pointSize of the UIFont used by the UILabel:

```
UILabel *label; // Your Label

UIFont *font = label.font;
label.font = [font fontWithSize:(font.pointSize - 4)];
```

This example reduces the font by 4 points.

Comment: still i'm getting same weight but the size has decreased:-(

Comment: Font **weight** (what the OP is asking to change) is the thickness of the line used to draw the letters: e.g. extra-bold, bold, regular, medium, light, ultra-light, etc. It has nothing to do with font **size**.